# How do I update only a panel on check changed?

Tags: c#, updatepanel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="up1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">

<ContentTemplate>

<asp:CheckBox ID="chkParent" runat="server" autopostback="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkParent_OnCheckedChanged" />

<asp:DataList ID="ChildList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ChildList_OnItemDataBound">

 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

protected void chkParent_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 this.ChildList.DataSource = this.ChildValues;
this.ChildList.DataBind();
}
```

On check changed of parent, child gets updated but the entire page also loads. Any way to avoid it?